# Navigationbar is overlapping and not long enough at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

So my navigation bar is living it's own life right now by overlapping footer and at the same time not being long enough. This varies depending on how long the page becomes.

[[image]]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to better help you, would you please update your question to contain all relevant code in a [minimal, complete & verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, providing screenshots of the problem and details of what you’ve tried, make it much more likely that you’ll get a useful answer. 

For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your CSS file where the styling for your nav bar was defined and set the position to relative.

```
#nav {
                    position: relative;
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 0.8em;
    }
```

Comment: Please share your css and HTML code snippet, it will be helpful for us to provide solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,*after{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix::after
{
content:"";
display: table;
clear:both;
}

.header{
    height: 15vh; /*heigh is 20% of the view port*/
    background-color: aquamarine;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.container{
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
 
 
   

}
.container__nav
{
width: 24%;
height: 100%;
color: white;
background-color: blue;
float: left;
border:1px solid black;
}
.nav-item{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style: none;
}

.main-block__container{
width:75%;
height: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.footer{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:15vh ;
    background-color: purple;
    color:white;

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
   
                <header class="header">
                        this is my header
                    </header>
                    <main>
                        
                                <div class="container clearfix">
                                    <div class="container__nav">
                                        <nav class="list">
                                                <ul>
                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                                        home
                                                        </li>
                                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                            All
                                                            </li>
                                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                                shirts
                                                                </li>
                                                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                                                    pants
                                                                    </li>
                                                                         <li class="nav-item">
                                                                         about
                                                                       </li>
                                                            </ul>
                                        </nav>
                            
                                    </div>
                                            <div class="main-block__container text-center">
                                                    main block
                                                </div>
                                </div>
                             
                   
            
            
                    </main>
                    <footer>
                        <div class="footer">
            this is a footer
                        </div>
            
    
       
    </body>
</html>
```

The element's overlapping occurs  when the element is out-of-flow ,which means that the element positioning do not take in consideration other elements positioning. it happens when position property is set to "absolute"/"fixed" for example.
generally to have control over the position of the elements in the layout, alongside with implementing of the layout concepts (grid/flex-box/floats), you have to use abstract units (%,vh,vw) to set the lengths values.

below very simple example of layout setup, to achieve something similar to what you meant:

I will be happy to answer any questions.